# php-amqplib connection error

Tags: php, php-amqplib

I'm just doing a test to try and get RabbitMQ to work with `php-amqplib`. I've just edited the question so that it's using the right port. Any ideas on this?

This is my PHP file...

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env php
2 <?php
3
4 require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
5
6 $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
7 $dotenv->load();
8
9 $sample_msg = "0% chance of rain!";
10
11 $amqpConnection = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection(
12     getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
13     getenv('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
14     getenv('RABBITMQ_USER'),
15     getenv('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
16     getenv('RABBITMQ_VHOST')
17 );
18
19 $amqpChannel = $amqpConnection->channel();
20 $amqpChannel->queue_declare(getenv('SFTP_RABBITMQ_QUEUE'), false, true, false, false);
21
22 $msg = new AMQPMessage($sample_msg);
23 $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
24
25 echo " [x] Sent $sample_msg\n";
```

This is my .env...

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=dev.website.co.uk
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672 // ammended
RABBITMQ_VHOST=/
RABBITMQ_LOGIN=xxxxxx
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

SFTP_RABBITMQ_QUEUE=my_test_queue
```

This is the composer.json...

```
{
    "name": "neil/sftp-user-create",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.7",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
        },
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
             "name": "Me",
             "email": "my@email-address.com"
                                                             }
     ]
}
```

This is the error I get...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:214
Stack trace:
#0 /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(149): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
#1 /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(106): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(522): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(570): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(0)
#4 /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(225): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\Abstr in /home/neil/PhpstormProjects/sftp-user-create/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 214
```

Comment: You say RabbitMQ is configured on port 15672 - are you sure? That's commonly used for the admin interface, with the actual server running on **5672**.

Comment: With port 5672 I get a broken pipe, not connected error. Ok, you're right so I need to figure out what's happening with the broken pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. In you .env file you declared `RABBITMQ_LOGIN` yet in your code you are using `RABBITMQ_USER`, that gives you empty login and "Broken pipe" errors after you fixed connection port as @iainn mentioned
2. `$channel->basic_publish` you don't have any variable named `$channel`, it should be `$amqpChannel`
3. In `basic_publish` your last argument should be the name of the queue you want to send message to, so it should be the same as in `queue_declare` that is `getenv('SFTP_RABBITMQ_QUEUE')`

Fix this in your code:

```
$amqpConnection = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection(
     getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
     getenv('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
     getenv('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'), // Use _LOGIN as declared in .env
     getenv('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
     getenv('RABBITMQ_VHOST')
);
```

(...)

```
// Use $amqpChannel as you declared it earlier in code
// And use the same queue name in last parameter as you used in queue_declare
$amqpChannel->basic_publish($msg, '', getenv('SFTP_RABBITMQ_QUEUE'));
```